# How to make a custom rewrite with PHP MVC?

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller

I've started writing my own PHP MVC Framework and everything is working well expect custom URLs.

I want `http://example.com/featured` to be redirect to `index.php?tab=2&url=home/index`

and that's my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

# url should not point a directory or a file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# redirect all requests to index.php
RewriteRule ^featured$ index.php?tab=2&url=home/index [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

but it's not working. Any ideas why it would not be working?

Answer (score 1):

I've finally figured it out by myself.

I put `RewriteRule ^featured$ index.php?tab=2&url=home/index [NC]` above RewriteCond's and it worked.